Short sequences exact on left and right, but not in the middle
Hopefully a quick one I'd like to check with you.

Assume $R$ is a commutative unital ring and let $A,B,B^\prime,C$ be $R$-modules of finite rank. Suppose we have two sequences $$0\rightarrow A \hookrightarrow B \twoheadrightarrow C \rightarrow 0$$$$0 \rightarrow A \hookrightarrow B^\prime \twoheadrightarrow C \rightarrow 0$$ which are exact on the left and right (making the left maps injective and right maps surjective).
Question: If we additionally assume that $B\subseteq B^\prime$, does it then in fact follow that $B=B^\prime$?
I'm inclined to say no since this would likely additionally require exactness in the middle (in which case one can argue via ranks over $R$), but I am struggling to find a counterexample.

Thanks in advance,
M

For instance, $B'=B\oplus M$ for any $M$, $A=B=C$ with $A\to B'$ and $B'\to C$ the natural inclusion/projection maps.

Ah yes it seems so obvious now. Apologies for my silly oversight and thanks for the example!
